# Redirect requests to Django application using Apache

Tags: php, python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have an Apache web-server and a PHP application. It all works great. The `httpd.conf` file at this moment looks like so:

```
...
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
...
Listen 8080
DocumentRoot "c:/Apache242/htdocs"
<Directory "c:/Apache242/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

As you can see, I've already downloaded mod_wsgi.so and when I restart Apache it's all ok. So, when I go to `localhost:8080`, I see my PHP application running. Well done. Now, I have a second teene-weeny Django application. It's not even a full-blown application, because it's role will be to answer to one certain request from the same PHP application. Still, I will call it Django application. I run it like so:

```
C:\django\project> python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8081
```

As you can see I run a non-production server, but it works good. When I go to 127.0.0.1:8081, I see the result returned from my index view:

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world")
```

So, it's just a simple Hello world page and it works. Now what I want is to use Apache server, so that when I go to `localhost:8080/django`, I would see the very same Hello world page. I do not know how to implement this. Many solutions are based on virtual hosts, but I do not want to configure them (just because virtual hosts do not work in my situation). So if you have any suggestions, you are welcome. Thanks!

**EDIT**

I managed to create a virtual host for my PHP application. So, the httpd-vhosts.conf file looks like so:

```
Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache242/htdocs"
    <Directory c:/Apache242/htdocs>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I wonder, how I should configure it to redirect requests from localhost:8080/django to my Django application.

**EDIT**

It seems like I tried everything in the world. Now I've just tried to create one and only one virtual host just to service my Django project and I failed. Here are some prerequisites that I have:

- Python 2.7.12, MSC 1500 32bit on win32.
- Apache/2.4.23 (Win64), VC10
- mod_wsgi-py27-VC9.so for Apache24-win64-VC10

And this is how my virtual host file looks like now:

```
Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache242/htdocs/django"
    ServerName localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Apache242/htdocs/django/accent/wsgi.py"
    <Directory "C:/Apache242/htdocs/django/accent">
        Options +ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

When I reload Apache, I see it's all ok. Great. But when I go to localhost:8080, I get "Internal Server Error". And this is the whole stack trace from Apache error log:

```
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:33.340929 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8212:tid 300] AH00430: Parent: Child process 9532 exited successfully.
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:34.241980 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 4652:tid 300] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.9+.
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:34.242980 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 4652:tid 300] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.6.
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:34.242980 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4652:tid 300] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) mod_wsgi/4.4.6 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:34.242980 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4652:tid 300] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC10 Server built: Jul  9 2016 11:59:00
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:34.242980 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4652:tid 300] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Apache242\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache242'
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:34.245981 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4652:tid 300] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 10960
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:34.695006 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 10960:tid 172] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.9+.
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:34.696006 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 10960:tid 172] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.6.
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:34.753010 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10960:tid 172] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.295127 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990] mod_wsgi (pid=10960): Target WSGI script 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/django/accent/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.295127 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990] mod_wsgi (pid=10960): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/django/accent/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.295127 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.295127 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]   File "C:/Apache24/htdocs/django/accent/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.296127 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.296127 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.7.11-py2.7.egg\\django\\core\\wsgi.py", line 2, in <module>
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.296127 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]     from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.296127 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.7.11-py2.7.egg\\django\\core\\handlers\\wsgi.py", line 11, in <module>
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.297127 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]     from django import http
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.297127 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.7.11-py2.7.egg\\django\\http\\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.297127 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]     from django.http.cookie import SimpleCookie, parse_cookie
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.297127 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.7.11-py2.7.egg\\django\\http\\cookie.py", line 3, in <module>
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.298128 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]     from django.utils.encoding import force_str
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.298128 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.7.11-py2.7.egg\\django\\utils\\encoding.py", line 10, in <module>
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.298128 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]     from django.utils.six.moves.urllib.parse import quote
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.298128 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.7.11-py2.7.egg\\django\\utils\\six.py", line 90, in __get__
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.299128 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]     result = self._resolve()
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.299128 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.7.11-py2.7.egg\\django\\utils\\six.py", line 158, in _resolve
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.299128 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]     module = _import_module(self.mod)
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.299128 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.7.11-py2.7.egg\\django\\utils\\six.py", line 80, in _import_module
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.299128 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]     __import__(name)
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.299128 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]   File "C:\\Python27\\Lib\\urllib.py", line 26, in <module>
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.301128 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]     import socket
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.301128 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]   File "C:\\Python27\\Lib\\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.301128 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990]     import _socket
[Fri Dec 02 14:02:54.301128 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10960:tid 752] [client ::1:54990] ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 \xed\xe5 \xff\xe2\xeb\xff\xe5\xf2\xf1\xff \xef\xf0\xe8\xeb\xee\xe6\xe5\xed\xe8\xe5\xec Win32.
```

I do not know what is wrong with that.

**EDIT**

This is what I have in settings.py:

```
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']

USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True

INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)
```

**EDIT**

It seems like I tried dozens of virtual host configurations, but none of them works. This is the last configuration, that I tried:

```
Listen 8080
WSGIPythonPath C:/Apache242/htdocs/django
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache242/htdocs/django"
    ServerName localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias / C:/Apache242/htdocs/django/accent/wsgi.py
    <Directory C:/Apache242/htdocs/django/accent>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Files>
    </Directory>
    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache restarts well, but when I go to localhost:8080, I still see the very same Internal Server Error. So, I guess my question now should be - does anybody use Apache with Django?

**EDIT**

Now I start to believe that it's all because of wsgi.py file. In my case it looks like:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "accent.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

But I do not know how to fix it. PS. I do not have virtual environment for Python, I just installed it globally.

Comment: did you tried to make a redirection with condition on path /django or a rewrite rule ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: I would suggest upgrading your Python version to a newer version to start with. It isn't usually a good idea to use a mod_wsgi module compiled for a newer Python version, even though just a patch level difference, with an older Python installation.

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton. Hello! As for upgrading Python, I have s strict requirement to use Python 2.7, because I need to use one library that is supported just in this Python version.

Comment: By the way, I find this line in the error.log "Runtime using Python/2.7.6." really interesting, because I do not have Python 2.7.6 on my windows machine. I have Python 2.7.12. So, it's really strange that Apache uses some rubbish.

Comment: The 2.7.6 is because it is finding a python27.dll for that version. You might have installed 2.7.6 for all users at one point, but when installed 2.7.12 installed it only for yourself or something. That runtime message is because the dll used is saying it is that version. That why I was talking about upgrading, not to Python 3, but latest 2.7. Suggest you track down how many Python versions you have installed. If you find the proper dll for 2.7.12, add a line ``Loadfile "c:/path/to/python27.dll`` just before ``LoadModule`` for ``wsgi_module``. That will force load it first.

Comment: Also set ``WSGIPythonHome "c:/path/to"`` after the ``LoadModule``, where the path is to the location of Python install. What ``sys.prefix`` would give for it from interpreter. That and ``LoadFile`` will make sure using correct installation.

Comment: Thank you, Graham! Your advice was incredibly valuable! Besides, this your article was also helpful to me - https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst

Answer (score 0):

You can try an htaccess file in root php directory, i'm not sure but you something like :

```
Options -Indexes
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^/django(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8081$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Sorry, if I did not stress if well, but I do not want to use Django default server, which is not for production. That is why I added wsgi_module to httpd.conf.

Comment: ok then change Listen 8080 to Listen 8081 , and restart apache

Comment: And should I specify anything connected to wsgi? I'm asking this, because the request is redirected to Django application. It's not just another PHP script, that should handle this request

Comment: so you need to create a virtual host for that , you can't have one conf for several site exceptions

Comment: Thanks for that. It now seems, like I managed to create a virtual host. Now my PHP application runs on a virtual host. It's ok, I will post its contents in a second, And would you be so kind to share, how a virtual host for Django application would look like?

Comment: Do not know why they are downvoting your answer. To me it seems like you are in the right direction,

Comment: http://django-project-skeleton.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apache2_vhost.html  <= this can helps you

Comment: Would you be so kind to have a look at the update I did to my question? Thanks!